# Overload Jinja2 autoescape for (La)TeX

Tags: markup, jinja2

Is it possible to overload Jinja2's `autoescape` so that it escapes something in a user-specified way (i.e. something other than HTML such as LaTeX)?

Here's an example trying to escape `TeX`.

```
import jinja2

class MyEnv(jinja2.Environment):
    def __init__(self, filters={}, globals={}, tests={},
        loader=None, extensions=[], **kwargs):

        super(MyEnv, self).__init__(
            autoescape          = True,
        )

template = MyEnv().from_string("""\documentclass[{{ class }}]
         \\begin{document}
         {{ content }}
         \end{document}
     """)

print template.render({
    'class':'memoir',
    'content': '{bob} <-- is escaped',
    })
```

When you run the above, it outputs:

```
 \documentclass[memoir]
     \begin{document}
     {bob} &lt;-- is escaped
     \end{document}
```

The problem here is that HTML escaping is used. So `{` and `}` should be escaped, but they're not, and `<` is converted to `&lt;` but it should not be.

I'd like to overload the escape function that Jinja2 uses to escape variables.

My first thought is to overload `finalize` and disable `autoescape`. e.g.

```
import jinja2

class MyEnv(jinja2.Environment):
    def __init__(self, filters={}, globals={}, tests={},
        loader=None, extensions=[], **kwargs):

        super(MyEnv, self).__init__(
            autoescape          = False, # turn off autoescape
            finalize            = self.finalize,
        )

    def finalize(self, s):
        import re
        if isinstance(s, jinja2.Markup):
            return s
        s = s.replace('\\', '')
        s = s.replace('~', '\\textasciitilde')
        s = re.sub(r'([#|^|$|&|%|{|}])', r'\\\1', s)
        s = re.sub(r'_', r'\\_', s)

        return jinja2.Markup(s)


template = MyEnv().from_string("""\documentclass[{{ class }}]
         \\begin{document}
         {{ content }}
         \end{document}
     """)

print template.render({
    'class':'memoir',
    'content': '{bob} <-- is escaped',
    })
```

The output is incorrect, because the main text isn't made into `Markup` (i.e. a string flagged as safe):

```
documentclass[memoir]
     begin\{document\}
     \{bob\} <-- is escaped
     end\{document\}
```

If I set `autoescape` to True, and leave in finalize it *almost* works (and in this example, it does work):

```
\documentclass[memoir]
     \begin{document}
     \{bob\} <-- is escaped
     \end{document}
```

Turning `autoescape` on works because it makes the main body of text for the template as `Markup` (i.e. safe).

However, here's where the problem lies, if I change the input to a list that's `join`ed:

```
template = MyEnv().from_string("""\documentclass[{{ class }}]
         \\begin{document}
         {{ content|join("  > a & b > "|safe) }}
         \end{document}
     """)

print template.render({
    'class':'memoir',
    'content': ['A&B', 'C<D'],
    })
```

When I run this I get:

```
\documentclass[memoir]
     \begin{document}
     A&amp;B  > a & b > C&lt;D
     \end{document}
```

It would seem HTML `autoescape` is being run on the elements of 'content', rather than `finalize`. The simplest solution, provided Jinja2 and its autoescaping are loosely coupled, would seem to be to overload a autoescape function. I can't seem to figure that out, and the best I've come up with is the `finalize` function.

Is there a better way to handle escaping of `TeX` than overloading the `finalize` function? Can one overload `autoescape`?

For example, could one install a custom Markup package? (a choice I'd prefer to avoid)

Thank you for reading.

Comment: It would seem others have contemplated this problem See e.g. https://bitbucket.org/leonidas/jinja2-autoescape/src/434d9b0b3b4d/jinja2/utils.py#cl-497

Comment: I stumbled upon the very same problem. This [PR](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/535) fixes the call of the `finalize` method on the template code; if it were to approved, your code would work.